# Bit field manipulation-setting a bit

Tags: c, bit-fields

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct s{
      int bit_fld:3;
    };
    s a;
    a.bit_fld=0x10;
    a.bit_fld =( a.bit_fld | (1<<2));
    printf("%x\n",a.bit_fld);
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs `fffffffc`.

I tried to do manual calculation of the output and I could not get the output that the compiler produced.

`bit_fld = 00010000 and (1<<2) = 0100` oring both wil result in `00010100` which is `0x14` in hexadecimal.
Why my perception of the output is wrong ? Help me to understand where I'm mistaken.

Comment: Actually, `bit_fld` is `0000100b` and not `0001000b`.

Comment: Notice any compiler warnings? (On your actual code since the above wouldn't compile)

Comment: 0x10 = 16 decimal which is outside the valid range for your 3 bit bit-field. Or as `gcc -Wall` would say: `bitfield.c:9: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
`.

Comment: @Paul R:Yeah you are right paul.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a.bit_fld` is only 3 bits big, it can't store the value `0x10`. Behavior is implementation-defined, but in this case it has probably stored 0.

Then `1 << 2` is binary `100` as you say. Assuming we did store 0 at the first step, the result of `( a.bit_fld | (1<<2))` is an `int` with value 4 (binary `100`).

In a signed 2's complement 3-bit representation, this bit pattern represents the value -4, so it's not at all surprising if -4 is what you get when you store the value 4 to `a.bit_fld`, although again this is implementation-defined.

In the `printf`, `a.bit_fld` is promoted to `int` before passing it as a vararg. The 2's complement 32 bit representation of -4 is `0xfffffffc`, which is what you see.

It's also undefined behavior to pass an `int` instead of an `unsigned int` to `printf` for the `%x` format. It's not surprising that it appears to work, though: for varargs in general there are certain circumstances where it's valid to pass an `int` and read it as an `unsigned int`. `printf` isn't one of them, but an implementation isn't going to go out of its way to stop it appearing to work.

Comment: :I have understood now what a big mistake i have made by declaring bit_fld as 3 bit and thinking that it stores a 8 bit value.

Comment: :if the bit_fld is a 8 bit then (1<<2) will be typecasted to contain the value 00000100.Is my assumption right?

Comment: @Angus: arithmetic in C (including the `|` operator) is always done in at least an `int`, so `1<<2` is converted to `int` (well, in fact it's an `int` all along), and so is the value of `a.bit_fld`. Then the result is converted back to the type of the bit field for storage. At least, that's the defined behavior, the implementation is allowed to operate on narrower values for efficiency, provided the result is the same.